# PHP foreach with null value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have currently a problem with a foreach loop. I have a table with string value or null value and when I use a foreach to display it, there is no line break but with a for loop, it displays it correctly.
My foreach code:

```
foreach($table_iban_out as $element){
    echo $element.'<br/>';
}
```

And my for code:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($table_iban_out);$i++){
    echo $table_iban_out[$i].'<br/>';
}
```

For my table, [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhx8r.png) are null, [2]-[6] are strings and [7] is null again so I should have something like that on my page:

- void
- void
- string
- ...
- void again

I tried with a simple array

```
$table = array('a','','b');
```

and it works with a foreach loop, so anyone knows with it doesn't work with my $table_iban_out table?

Thanks

edit: Thanks for your help, this is what I get when I use

```
var_dump($table_iban_out);
```

[image]

edit 2:
So basically I have an Excel file with IBAN and I extract with:

```
function conversion($file){
    require_once '../../PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $column = convert($sheet->getHighestColumn());
    $row = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    for($i=0; $i<$column; $i++){ 
        for($j=1; $j<=$row; $j++){
            $table[$i][$j-1]= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$j);
        }
    }
    return $table;
}
```

Then I test $table with an other function element by element to see if the IBAN is correct and return $table_iban_out witch contains null if the IBAN is wrong and the IBAN if the IBAN is correct.

Comment: `var_dump($table_iban_out);` and show us **exactly** what you have there

Comment: It is pretty unreadable.
array(4) { [0]=> object(PHPExcel_Cell)#187 (6) { ["value":"PHPExcel_Cell":private]=> string(27) "FR9510096182571234567890123" ["calculatedValue":"PHPExcel_Cell":private]=> NULL ["dataType":"PHPExcel_Cell":private]=> string(1) "s" ["parent":"PHPExcel_Cell":private]=> object(PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_Memory)#168 (5) { ["parent":protected]=> object(PHPExcel_Worksheet)#166 (40) {

Comment: You do not have strings there... you have objects there....

Comment: @Zhang i have checked your example $table_iban_out = array('a','','b'); I got same answer for both "for loop"

Comment: @Zhang Please print by using echo "<pre>";var_dump($table_iban_out); echo "</pre>"; and getting the result pasting on it.

Comment: If this is an array of `PHPExcel_Cell` objects, then it very definitely isn't a `table with string value or null value`.... note that this is likely to cause you problems, because a PHPExcel_Cell object is actually a pointer to a currently active cell, and you can only have a single currently active cell at a time, so an array of cells will all point to a single, currently active cell

Comment: So what are you really trying to do? How are you creating this "array" of cell objects?

Comment: Change `$table[$i][$j-1]= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$j);` to `$table[$i][$j-1]= $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$j)->getValue();` when you're building your array.... or even use PHPExcel's built-in `toArray()` or `rangeToArray()` methods

Answer (score 0):

Because your elements are NOT strings but PHPExcel_Cell objects you must use

`$element->getValue()` instead of `$element`

```
foreach($table_iban_out as $element){
    echo $element->getValue().'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: In what way "didn't work"? Did you get an error message? Did the system crash and burn? Did it display incorrect values? Learn to explain your problem, and it makes it easier to help you..... "didn't work" IS NOT a valid diagnosis of a problem

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same output.